# Web view page is forced to close when Google assistant finishes talking

Tags: actions-on-google

When we have a simple response and basic card with link out button. See below code, if user clicks the link to open the web view page before Google assistant finishes reading. Once Google assistant finishes reading, the web view page is forced to close. User has to click the button again to open the web view. It looks like the the response gets reset when Google assistant activate the listening mode.

```
{
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "ssml": "<speak>\r\n  <audio src=\"…audio file location url…">some long text message\ r\n</speak>",
                "displayText": " some long text message”
              }
            },
            {
              "basicCard": {
                "title": "",
                "subtitle": "",
                "formattedText": "",
                "buttons": [
                  {
                    "title": "title",
                    "openUrlAction": {
                      "url": "… url…",
                      "urlTypeHint": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "isInSandbox": false
}
```